# Separate text on my textbox when there is a comma and send it to a new line?

Tags: vb.net

How can separate text on my textbox when there is a comma and send it to a new line?
this is my line of codes

```
If TextBox1.Text.Contains(", ") Then
    'TextBox2.Text = TextBox1.Text.Replace(", ", " ")
    TextBox1.Text.Replace(",", Environment.NewLine)
    TextBox2.Text = TextBox1.Text
    asa = TextBox3.Text
    TextBox3.Text = TextBox2.Text
    ListBox1.Items.Add(TextBox3.Text)
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

`String.Replace()` only returns the formatted string, you still need to assign the string that gets returned.

This:
`TextBox1.Text.Replace(",", Environment.NewLine)`

Should be: `TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Replace(",", Environment.NewLine)`